# How to get latest date from previous month in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the latest date from previous month and when I run this query:

```
select max(me_date) from table1 having month(me_date) = Month(max(me_date)) - 1
```

This gives me the latest date for the current month instead of previous. Any ideas?

Comment: I added the "sql-server" tag based on the title.  However, that code should generate a syntax error in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Your code would fail in almost any database, because of the use of non-aggregated functions in the `having` clause.

In general, if you want to filter data, you should do so before aggregation.  In SQL Server, I would suggest:

```
select max(me_date)
from table1
where me_date < dateadd(day, (1 - day(getdate())), convert(date, getdate())) and
      me_date >= dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, (1 - day(getdate())), convert(date, getdate())));
```

The above is index and optimizer friendly.  If you don't care about that, then a simpler formulation is:

```
where datediff(month, me_date, getdate()) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE()-1) AS 'Last Month';

[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use having without group by clause, hence the error.

I tested The following query; it works fine in MySQL

Select distinct me_date from <table_name> where month(me_date) not in (select max(month(me_date)) from <table_name> ) order by me_date describe limit 1;

Alternatives of month() function would be datepart(month, me_date)
Or,
Extract (month from me_date)
Or,
Strftime('%m', me_date)

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the max(me_date) from previous month of max(me_date) of table1 then try this:

```
select max(me_date)
from table1
where datediff(month, me_date, (select max(me_date) from table1)) = 1;
```